# How does battery cell size affect voltage drop for a fix current load?

Tags: voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

For a fixed current load, will the voltage drop be larger in a small cell or a big cell battery? Why?

Comment: What do you mean by small and big? What circuit are you describing? As is, your question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean "fixed current draw,"  which may be difficult to achieve if the battery's voltage changes in the first place.

So let's try this alternative: suppose the battery is connected to a certain resistor. Do you want to know whether the size of the battery (but same rated voltage) affects the voltage it can maintain?  "Size isn't everything."  There's a concept called "internal resistance" which is a measure of a battery's ability to maintain a constant voltage as the external resistance changes.   As it turns out, in general a larger battery, which can be thought of as some small batteries in parallel, will have smaller internal resistance, meaning the voltage will droop less for a given external resistance.  This is primarily because a battery's voltage drops as its internally stored energy is released.  Since the power (energy/unit time) dumped into a given resistor  is a smaller percentage of the large battery's capacity than the small battery's, the voltage droop happens more slowly.